# Check a map on $D_k$ is a homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $D_k$ be the dihedral group of order $2k$, it has presentation $\langle x,y : x^k = y^2 = xyxy = 1\rangle$.

Given a map $\phi$ (it is actually a bijection)
$$x\mapsto x^i \quad y\mapsto x^j y$$
where $i$ is reveletive prime to $k$, and $0<j<k$. I want to check that $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

I need to show that 
$$\phi(xy) = \phi(x)\phi(y)$$ 
but how can I write out $\phi(xy)$ explicitly?

Do I need to define a new homomorphism $\tilde\phi$ from the free group of two symbols $F_{\{x,y\}} \rightarrow D_k$ and try to use the isomorphism theorem to finish the argument? I guess there would be a simpler way.

Comment: You just have to check that $x^i$ and $x^jy$ both satisfy the relations that $x$ and $y$ satisfy.

Comment: In $D_k$, I can see that this is easy to check, but as a free group quotient out some relation, how can I check that $(x^jy)(x^jy)  = 1$?

Comment: Just do it in $D_k$, then. You should think of $D_k$ as $F_\{x,y\}/\langle x^k,y^2,xyxy\rangle$

Comment: Thank you for the help. If $x$ is rotation and $y$ is reflection, then I can argue by drawing a picture that $x^jyx^jy  = 1$, if they are just symbols as in $F_{\{x,y\}}/\{x^k, y^2, xyxy\}$ how can I argue it is the identity?

Comment: You have three relations to check. You can use that $x^k=y^2=xyxy=1$. I can check that $(x^i)^k=(x^k)^i=1^i=1$. Can you do the other two? Start computing $(x^jy)^2$ and $(x^i)(x^jy)(x^i)(x^jy)$.

Comment: I was stuck on checking the 2nd one, and I just figured it out, thank you! And why is this enough to conclude that $\phi$ is a homomorphism?

Comment: Because $x$ and $y$ generate $D_k$ and you've checked that wherever they map to satisfy the relevant relations so their images determine the homomorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer follows from [Ravi](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/23522/ravi)'s comments above:

Since $x,y$ generate $D_k$, it suffice to check their images under $\phi$ are still contained in $D_k$ and thus their images determine the homomorphism $\phi:D_k \rightarrow D_k$.

$$(x^i)^k = x^{ki} = 1^i = 1, \\
(x^jy)^2 = x^jyx^jy = x\cdots x y{x(yy)\cdots x}y = \text{ (repeat) } = 1\\
x^{i+j}y x^{i+j}y = 1 \text{ (as above)}$$